# What to do about questions/answers that are unclear due to poor English?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I've seen a few posts where the person asking/answering are not able to express his/her thoughts because of poor english. At such times the person's question is *put on hold* and the person is asked to make changes or improve their question/answer. The most recent case being this one  https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/19497/revisions .

Instead of asking the person to improve their own posts using english , why not suggest the option of posting the details in their native language? We can get the basic details and understand(most of it) via a translator. Then all thats left to do is to put the translated details into the original post. Is this feasible ?

Comment: The case you use as an example was actually a case in which the OP showed very little effort, saying that he ["didn't want to keep on editing his question"](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19497/#comment26112_19497), as if he were doing us a favour. It's good to keep in mind that though we are here to help new users, they should also show some effort in salvaging their own questions. In that case, isn't it easier for the OP to use a translator herself, instead of us doing it? We can always edit the details, as long as the general point of the question is understood.

Comment: last part,they use native language and we translate it. The translated part may be completely different from what OP want to say. As we don't know what OP want to say ,we see translated part as the main and the response may deviate a lot. So as JNat says,OP should use translator.

Comment: Ohh okay understood. Silly of me to ask a question where the answer was obvious :p sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is understandable, then we will help the user as much as we can to fix the post into something presentable. However, if the user's English is too poor that you can't understand what the question is trying to ask, our site is probably not the place for such user.

In the case above, it wasted quite a lot of time and effort from several experienced users and (I think) it also annoyed the OP quite a bit with all the exchanges in the comment. While the end result is a somewhat OK question, it is quite counter-productive in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed, in every aspect.